# spark structured streaming: query incoming data via Hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive, spark-streaming

I am streaming data into Spark Structured Streaming 2.1.1 using Kafka with a writeStream() to append into parquet. This works.

I can create a temporary table over the parquet files using

```
spark.read.parquet ("/user/markteehan/interval24" ).registerTempTable("interval24")
```

However this is only visible in the same spark session; and the "read.parquet" must be re-run to collect new data. Setting ".queryName()" for the writeStream doesnt create a table in the hive metastore.

What is the best technique to run SQL dynamically on the parquet data?

Comment: Register a global table instead of a temp one in order to use the table outside the session (that might only be in Spark 2.2)

Comment: Yes, this seems to be spark 2.2. I must stay on spark 2.1 for now.

Comment: I think there's a way to start the thriftserver, and if you can get its session,  any registered tables are queryable through any external ODBC/JDBC connection

Comment: See here under streaming and SQL https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/30/diving-into-apache-spark-streamings-execution-model.html